# best way to manage many small git instances

Tags: git, distributed

My distributed application runs on a large number of hosts, with each instance of the application having a small number of similar but different configuration files. I would like to begin tracking these configuration files in git.

The principal work flow would have the support staff editing the files in place on the distributed hosts, committing the changes locally, and periodically pushing those changes up to a central location/repo so we could recover them later, etc.

What's the best way to do this? The brute force way would be to create one upstream repo per distributed host and push/pull to/from them on a 1:1 basis, but this feels like a lot of overhead/hassle/admin given how few files would be tracked in each repo. Is there a way to have a single central repo with, say, subdirectories that correlate to each host's instance? I know how to do this in subversion (and maybe my thinking is all wrong because I'm too influenced by that model), but I'm stuck on the best way to do this in git.

Answer (score 0):

Subdirectories — no.  These have absolutely no special meaning in the Git data model (actually no meaning at all as there's even no way to add an empty directory under the Git's control).

But I'd just use separate branch for each host in the same repository: say, host "foo" pushes its sole branch it ever pushes out to the remote branch "foo", like in

```
git push origin master:foo
```

If you think you'd need to have several branches per host, just "namespace" your "target" branches by prefixing them: say, host "foo" would push its own branch" yadda" into "foo/yadda", like in

```
git push -u origin yadda:foo/yadda
```

(Using `-u` would make the next push simpler: `git push origin yadda` — please study the `git-push` manual page.)

To make what have been said possibly more clear, what gets pushed into what is by policy only: the name of a local branch does not have to be the same as the name of the "destination" remote branch and vice-versa.